# How to implement the OpenGL API in a custom arm os

Tags: opengl-es, arm, raspberry-pi4, osdev

I'm developing an operating system targetting the ARM architecture, more specifically, a RaspberryPi 4B. For that I've already managed to use the "Mailbox Property Interface" to draw some shapes on the screen. Out of curiosity I would like to know if it was possible to use OpenGL (or OpenGL ES, preferably) to render future more complex graphics. If possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It will be **tons** of work though, and you are on your own. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find out which driver the usual Raspberry Pi software uses, then adapt that driver to work on your OS. This is the code that interprets your OpenGL commands and translates them to the GPU's native language. Note there is both a kernel part and a user-space part.

It's probably not worth trying to write your own. Graphics is a whole field of study, it's like writing another OS just for the graphics card.